# Is logical AND between Twitter streaming API filter parameters possible?

Tags: twitter

I'm interested in gathering some Twitter data for my project, connecting to the stream and gathering data based on an number of locations **AND** a number of track keywords. However, as apparent in the docs, it appears that I will get **all** status postings that match either condition. Is it at all possible to filter based on location and track?

I'm querying for around 10 cities, and it seems like a crazy prospect to have to open up a pipe to all of them and then have to do my own keyword filtering on my end. I'll be throwing out 99.9% of the data I collect if this is required...

What is the right way to do this? Should I use the Search API instead? The rate limitation seems like an issue, and the Search API won't be capable of delivering the amount of data I'm interested in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't define any complex filters on streaming API; there is nothing wrong in throwing out 99.9% of tweets (just do it quickly - before wasting your CPU on processing them)